# Was The Decembrist always on the Blacklist?

Tags: the-blacklist

I've just seen S2E8, "The Decembrist", of *The Blacklist*. The Decembrist was listed as #12 on the Blacklist.

The Decembrist was the person who set up the rivalry between Berlin and Reddington. In the episode, the Decembrist turns out to be

> Alan Fitch.

But before this episode, Reddington didn't even know about the Decembrist. Yet he was #12 on the Blacklist.

Does this mean that

> Alan Fitch

already was on the Blacklist, at #12?

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, I dont think the "Blacklist" is a completed list in the story. Sure he has most of the names down.

> Even members of the "Cabal"maybe.

But as i see it, i believe the list is formed and ranked as Red discovers these people. Hence the list is probably one that is already compiled in the "future" after all blacklisters have been found. Another example of this is in

> episode "Berlin", where Red, up to that point, only knew someone was targeting his interest, but not who. Hence, the Blacklist name and rank must only been added after he known.

Another alternative idea: Red probably already knows about the Decembrist, as every other blacklister, and their work but not their identity. He has ranked them based on what they do. Hence he is hunting/catching/killing those he needs or poses an imminent threat to Keen or his Empire.

My wild guess, is he himself may be on the list, ranked #1.

Comment: I have always though that it was a ever growing ever changing check list. Some are know and named but like any list you think of new thinks to add to it and so on.

Comment: Agreed. Prob his way of keeping tabs on the criminal competition + watching over the few people he loves.

Comment: I think the Blacklist is why he vanished from his life in the first place. And he has just been adding to it and striking through names as he went along. My grand theory is that Red is not an actual bad guy. Just a guy that has gotten caught up in a roll. Like that story of the fish he told Keen in the prison in the middle of the ocean?

Comment: man! thats an interesting observation! If thats the case, his entire life(esp his screwups), the existence of his criminal empire, everything began with the pursuit of the blacklist. Everything else was adapting. Interesting!

Comment: It is... It explains some things like why he vanished in the first place. If he had gotten intell about a list (the future Blacklist) and decided to hunt it down (as a good guy)... I can just seen Red, the practical guy that he is seeing the only way to get his hands on said list is to become a force in the crime world. Then once he *has* the Blacklist he returns and joins up with Keen to hunt them down.